# Doubt related to wireless mouse

Tags: wireless, mouse, bluetooth

This is something new to me, so I need help, please.

I need to buy a wifi mouse, but I don't know if it's going to work on my Ubuntu 11.10. I've seen some mice here and all of them mention Windows or Mac. None of them mentions Linux.

So, what do you have to say? With the experience you have, do you know if this kind of mouse works normally on Linux (Ubuntu)? Do you recommend any specific brand?

Another doubt I have is... When they say "wifi" mouse, what is this "wifi" exactly? Is it bluetooth or a specific wifi system just for the mouse? All the mice I've seen come with a USB dongle. So, is this dongle a bluetooth adaptor or a specific wifi adaptor just for the mouse itself? I'm asking this because, if this dongle is a bluetooh one, I guess I won't need it because my laptop has a native bluetooth feature.

Thanks for your time, guys. :)

brunces

Answer (score 0):

I use a Logitech wireless mouse, but I think all of them work with Linux as well as with Windows or Mac.  I think this is one area in which you don't have to worry much about the OS.  (I can't say that they will all work perfectly, but I suspect you'd have a harder time finding one that didn't work.)

The dongle is not bluetooth but radio and it works extremely well. I'd guess any of the brands and models will do as well, although I'd recommend a model in which the dongle doesn't stick out very far (so it doesn't get broken or damaged).